ADM8318 hardware watchdog timer
Implementing a hardware watchdog in my application and not getting the expected result. I am using the ADM8318WCY from Analog Devices which has a typical reset timeout of 200ms, and a typical watchdog timeout of 1.6s.

From the waveform above, the WDI pin is toggled every 360ms (YELLOW), and active high RESET output (pin 3) of the ADM8318WCY is high and remains high. I am not sure this is right, and I expect it to be high when there is no clock pulse after the watchdog timeout (1.6s) elapses. But what I have observed is that when clock pulses is stopped, this PIN still remains HIGH. I have used a pullup and pulldown resistor, but it just remains high (see below image).

I stopped toggling the PIN, and the RESET pin still remain high.
On the other hand the active-low RESET output (pin 1) remains LOW. So it does not appear it is responding to the toggling WDI pin.
Any thought of why this is so?
My circuit below and datasheet here



It looks like the WDI signal isn't connected to the ADM and hence the WDT is being disabled. Can you check the WDI connection to the ADM pin?

Hi. Yes, I can confirm that it is connected.  See newly attached image. Thanks

Sorry I don't mean in the design, I mean in the assembly. Ideally, place a probe on the pin of U1 just to check.

Oh Yes, I do get same signal right on the pin.

The ADM8318WCY used was the ADM8318WCY46ARJZR7 which had a reset threshold of 4.63V. The VCC needed to be above this threshold for the RESET to pins to be asserted after the 1.6s timeout.
See link: https://ez.analog.com/power/f/q-a/589675/reset-pins-not-triggered
